# Display results from two lists in one list with one loop (Flask - Python)

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to display my result on an HTML page (index.html) in a list of links. I have two lists, first containing all the WebSite Name and the second their links. I want to display the name as clickable items.

My Lists :

```
name_list = ['Name1','Name2','Name3']
link_list = ['Link1','Link2','Link3']
```

What my Python code returns:

```
return render_template('index.html' , name_list =name_list , link_list =link_list , len1 = len(name_list ))
```

HTML code:

```
{% for i in range(0, len1) %}
      <li><a href={{link_list[i]}} >{{ name_list[i] }}</a></li> 
{% endfor %}
```

But I have two Errors:

First with the `len1` , because when I change my code to `range(0, 5)` (or any int) this line works.

```
TypeError: 'Undefined' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The second occured when I'm adding the postion of the element I want `name_list[i]`.

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'name_list' is undefined
```

Comment: Your code worked for me. This is probably a problem with your variable scope. Are you sure that `name_list` can be seen within your function?

Comment: You were right I had a problem of indentation in a function . It has solved an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple approach to solve your problem:

You combine the two lists with the python's builtin function `zip()`:

```
name_list = ['Name1','Name2','Name3']
link_list = ['Link1','Link2','Link3']
name_link_list = zip(name_list, link_list)
```

You simply return this:

```
return render_template('index.html' , name_link_list=name_link_list)
```

This returns a list of tuples of the form `[('Name1', 'Link1'), ('Name2', 'Link2'), ...]`, which you get in your HTML code using the index of each element. 0 for the **name**, 1 for the **link**.

And finally your HTML code:

```
<ul>
    {% for i in name_link_list %}
        <li><a href={{i[1]}} >{{ i[0] }}</a></li> 
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Definitely a more efficient approach

Comment: It solves my problem thanks ! Moreover I discorved a new function thanks to your explenations ;)